# Insert Query not able run on sql developer. Showing error ORA-00600

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, ora-00600

I am new to plsql and oracle database. I just created a table

```
CREATE TABLE contacts
( con_id number(4) PRIMARY key,
  company_name varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
  e_mail varchar2(30),
  last_date date default systimestamp,
  con_cnt number(3) check(con_cnt > 0)
);
```

it is successfully created but insert query

```
insert into CONTACTS(con_id, COMPANY_NAME, e_mail, last_date, con_cnt)
 VALUES (01,'hrSol','raj@gmail.com','12-12-12',12);
```

shows following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [12811], [284560], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
00600. 00000 -  "internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]"
*Cause:    This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program
           exceptions. It indicates that a process has encountered a low-level,
           unexpected condition. The first argument is the internal message
           number. This argument and the database version number are critical in
           identifying the root cause and the potential impact to your system.
Error starting at line : 75 in command -
update CONTACTS
SET e_mail = 'hrsol@gmail.com'
WHERE con_id = 01
Error at Command Line : 75 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: Closed Connection
```

I tried inserting values in other tables and it works fine. Just this table is giving the problem.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does that error message show for an _update_, rather than an insert?       
     
`Error starting at line : 75 in command -
update CONTACTS
SET e_mail = 'hrsol@gmail.com'
WHERE con_id = 01`       
     
Have you tried adding a `commit;` directly after the insert to double check that the insert is the problem?

Comment: There's a note on MOS for ORA-0600[12811] - see doc ID 138384.1. There seem to be several things that can cause this, depending on your Oracle version. You can see if any of those apply. Otherwise look for trace files for more information, search MOS with more details, and consider raising a service request.